# Why's this US Army soldier knocking his rifle magazine against his helmet?

Tags: black-hawk-down

What's he doing at  [1:52](https://youtu.be/86Ty4sOFZ00?t=113)? Why whop his M16A4 magazine at all? And why his head? Why not wallop it against the ground? It's dangerous  to conk your head in general.

Comment: They are wearing hamlets, I think there is a layer of soft cushion inside. They want to make sure all the bullets are well aligned, no dust or small stones inside which may cause jamming.

Comment: Please describe the action ion the clip. The video might be taken down.

Comment: Between this and their last question, it looks like they might be trolling.

Answer (score 3):

We see soldiers do this in other movies - Apocalypse Now (during the Ride of the Valkyries attack sequence) comes to mind - particularly because this is mimicked by the marines watching the sequence in the cinema during Jarhead.

I don't know if this is really done by some soldiers in the belief that it "settles" the rounds in the magazine and prevents jams.

What I do know is that my old instructors in the British TA specifically told us not to do this, as it might cause the feed clips to deform and that *would* cause a jam.

Answer (score 2):

Soldiers have been doing that for decades with the belief that it aligns the rounds with the back side of the magazine and therefore decreases the likelihood of a jam caused by a mis-aligned round.

That said, some people point out that this should make no difference to a properly built and maintained weapon.